# Embedding twitter posts

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

> Is is possible to embed twitter posts on Politics Stack Exchange?

Of course we can quote someone and post a reference, with a link to the original tweet. Also, it is possible to snapshot it and post the image. But I believe embedding the tweet, as many media outlets do, should yield better presentation quality.

> Should this be encouraged?

With politicians like Trump often posting tweets containing official statements and some discussions between public figures taking place over twitter, embedding said posts could be something alike to enclosing evidence in the question/answer being posted. Such evidence being less mutable and sometimes more reliable than Wikipedia.

So what are the community's thought on this?

Answer (score 4):

That's already possible, just go to [a tweet on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/710833460466864129), then click the little arrow on the right and select '*Embed Tweet*'. Copy the quote and you get the result below (I added a single `>`).

> 50,000 developers can't be wrong - except those who identify as "rockstars". https://t.co/0AULWSF9Zi [#DevSurvey2016](https://twitter.com/hashtag/DevSurvey2016?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) [pic.twitter.com/JH6rq5Xq04](https://t.co/JH6rq5Xq04)— Stack Overflow (@StackOverflow) [18 March 2016](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/710833460466864129?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Code:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en-gb"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">50,000 developers can&#39;t be wrong - except those who identify as &quot;rockstars&quot;. <a href="https://t.co/0AULWSF9Zi">https://t.co/0AULWSF9Zi</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/DevSurvey2016?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#DevSurvey2016</a> <a href="https://t.co/JH6rq5Xq04">pic.twitter.com/JH6rq5Xq04</a></p> &mdash; Stack Overflow (@StackOverflow) <a href="https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/710833460466864129?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">18 March 2016</a> </blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: This is nice, but I cannot see the code trying to edit because I get the message "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites". Also I would not have noticed it was embedded, since unlike the media outlets I mentioned, the twitter block layout with the picture and verified profile check is not shown.

Comment: @Mefitico okay, if you go to [this link](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/710833460466864129), then select the little arrow next to the follow button and click *'Embed Tweet'*, then you can see the code too. While it doesn't show any official Twitter logo, it does copy all relevant links in the tweet. So it's less tedious than having to copy and link to the tweet manually. Now you just say you are quoting a tweet and copy this code.

Comment: @Mefitico as for fully embedding tweets, there's [a meta post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142019/387405) with some reasons why this isn't done stated in the answer.